# Send GeoData In Background

Tags: android, ios, iphone

This is a technical without any code. I just need to now if the concept is possible.

Sorry for the following scenario. But it makes it really clear what I need.
In Pokemon Go you had to have to app active(not in background) in order to see new Pokemon.
Is it impossible to send GeoData in background ?

I want to send GeoData using the alarm manager, lets say every 5 Minutes. 
Is that actually possible ? Or does android forbid fetching GeoData in background ?

It would also be nice to know if thats possible in IOS.

Comment: I would say it's possible and the only problems would be with Android's power saving features like the Doze mode. But of course there are ways to keep a Service alive.

Answer (score 1):

You can write services and AlarmManager to do so. Simply register your application in services and call alarmMangaer.setRepeat() method to start your code of serverside or any other operation you want (in this case get geolocation of device) to do in onStart() method of services.